# How can I move bitizens to a different apartment?

Tags: tiny-tower

I want to demolish one of my apartment floors because it's really ugly but I want to keep the Bitizens in it. I built a new residential floor to move them to but now I'm thinking it's not possible to move Bitizens to new apartments.

Help!

Answer (score 3):

You can make a deal with a friend, send them to the friend and when they send them back, move them into the apartment of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in Tiny Tower you do not have the option of moving individual Bitizens to another apartment floor.  Once they have taken up residential space on one of your floors, they are tied there permanently until you evict them.